# On ICS ListView not scrolling

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

hi all I am trying to scroll to up using this line of code listView.smoothScrollToPosition(listCustomAdapter.getCount()); . it working for on Samsung Galaxy with 2.2 OS , but it not working for ICS by HTC One V.Anyhow guide me why it is not working for ICS ?I test on another HTC mobile having OS 2.2 it working fine and list scrolling up after each incoming text messages.note my listView working for show the incoming chat text messages.Anyone guide how I can scroll up listView or where I am doing that not workable on ICS .
Thanks . .

Answer (score 0):

hi thanks I got the solution for this .here was need to put now it working fine ..

```
listview.setTranscriptMode(ListView.TRANSCRIPT_MODE_ALWAYS_SCROLL);
listview.setStackFromBottom(true);
```